# Populate jQuery plugin defaults from json file

Tags: jquery, json

I'm building a jQuery plugin, that allows users to use custom themes, called as options like so:

```
$('element').myFunction({
  theme: '/path/to/theme'
});
```

The theme contains a file `theme-info.json`, which contains the name of the theme, as well as some other metadata, and is read by the plugin when it is initalised:

```
{
  "name": "themeName",
  "author": "authorName"
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is populate the default options for the plugin, with an array of plugin options from the json file within the theme, so that they can be overridden when calling the function, as though they had been hardcoded like so:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function (options) {
  var defaults = {
    theme: '/default/theme/path',
    themeOptions: {
      // values called from json
      option1: 'value1',
      option2: 'value2'
    }
  }
}
```

and then called with the plugin:

```
$('element').myFunction({
  theme: '/path/to/theme',
  themeOptions: {
    option1: 'value1',
    option2: 'value2'
  }
});
```

Is it actually possible to read a JSON file into the defaults in this way? And if so, how is it done?

**UPDATE**

Playing with it a bit further, I've managed to get *something* returned, but I'm struggling to do anything with it. Here's the AJAX call to get the theme metadata and options:

```
$.ajax({
  url: defaults.theme + 'theme-info.json',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success:  function(data) {
    themeName = data.name;
    var data = $.extend(true, defaults, data);
    var options = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
  }
});
```

I then use

```
act.prepend('<script>
  var parts = \'[' + JSON.stringify(defaults.themeOptions) + ']\';
  var themeOptions = $.parseJSON(parts);
  var themeOptions = themeOptions[0];
</script>');
```

Which prints the following at the top of the target container

```
var parts = '[{"backgroundColor":"#FF5859","testVar":"Tada!"}]';
var themeOptions = $.parseJSON(parts);
var themeOptions = themeOptions[0];
```

Then in the theme, I can use the variable `themeOptions.backgroundColor` which loads the values from the JSON brilliantly. However, the user defined options when calling the plugin are not overwriting the default values from the JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean read the JSON file remotely?

Comment: It's in the same directory as the plugin. I'm calling it using $.ajax later on to return the theme metadata, which is working fine, I just don't know how to put values from the JSON file into the defaults array

Comment: Why doesn't storing the return value from `$.ajax` into `defaults.themeOptions` work?

Comment: if Iput

    `themeOptions: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: defaults.theme + 'theme-info.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success:  function(data) {
          return data.themeOptions;
        }
      });
    }`

all I get returned is a string containing the above ajax function, rather than the results that the query produced

Answer (score 0):

have a look to [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

With this method u can read a json file on the fly.